# How can I group and sum data by day of the week?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two arrays, **nsDates** which hold dates and **values**, which holds values (Int), and I want to sum the values according to the day of the week.

I found several answers on this for SQL but nothing in swift/objective-c.  The code I have written below does the trick.  But it is slow and verbose.  What is the computationally most efficient way to group and sum the values according to the day of the week?  Any help would be much appreciated !

I create a function to get the day of the week (i.e. Sunday = 1 etc)

```
func getDayOfWeek(somedate:NSDate)->Int? {

    let calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let dateComps:NSDateComponents = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitWeekday , fromDate: somedate)
    let dayOfWeek:Int = dateComps.weekday
    return dayOfWeek
}
```

I initialise arrays that will hold the values that I am about to pass.

```
var friday = [Int]()
var saturday = [Int]()
var sunday = [Int]()
var monday = [Int]()
var tuesday = [Int]()
var wednesday = [Int]()
var thursday = [Int]()
```

I pass the dates in nsDates into the func getDayOfWeek, to get the day of the week, and if it is 1 then I append the corresponding value from the values array to the sunday array I initialized above, if dayOfWeek == 2 I append it to the monday array etc.

```
func appendValuesPerDayOfWeek(){
    for i in 1...nsDates.count{
      var dayOfWeek = getDayOfWeek(nsDates[i-1])
            if dayOfWeek == 1{
                sunday.append(values[i-1])}
            if dayOfWeek == 2{
                monday.append(values[i-1])}
            if dayOfWeek == 3{
                tuesday.append(values[i-1])}
            if dayOfWeek == 4{
                wednesday.append(values[i-1])}
            if dayOfWeek == 5{
                thursday.append(values[i-1])}
            if dayOfWeek == 6{
                friday.append(values[i-1])}
            if dayOfWeek == 7{
                saturday.append(values[i-1])}
        }
}
```

I execute the function

```
appendValuesPerDayOfWeek()
```

To get the sum of the values for each day of the week I finally I sum the elements of each array.

```
let sumMonday = monday.reduce(0,+)
let sumTuesday = tuesday.reduce(0,+)
let sumWednesday = wednesday.reduce(0,+)
let sumThursday = thursday.reduce(0,+)
let sumFriday = friday.reduce(0,+)
let sumSaturday = saturday.reduce(0,+)
let sumSunday = sunday.reduce(0,+)
```

Comment: Your code is faulty, please correct it.

Comment: Replacing `friday`, `saturday` with another array would be a good start ...

Comment: not sure what you mean, the code works fine, however i have not pasted in the arrays...

Comment: @karlml `func getDayOfWeek(nsdate)->Int?` is not going to work. And `for i in 1...nsDates.count` seems to be ripped out of context somehow.

Comment: I don't get it, do you want me to paste in the arrays..?  values and nsDates?

Comment: @karlml no, that is not needed. But that code snippet is not expressive enough and confusing IMO. Better rip it apart into pieces and add some comments.

Comment: @sebastian-dressler Ok, done, I also renamed the last function, it was misleading I admit

Answer (score 3):

Rather than have separate variables per day of week, you would probably be better off with a dictionary that maps days of the week to values.

Given this change, you could write a function, `groupedReduce`, that takes both a combining function and a grouping function and returns a dictionary where each group is combined:

```
func groupedReduce
  <S: SequenceType, K: Hashable, U>
  (source: S, initial: U, 
   combine: (U, S.Generator.Element) -> U, 
   groupBy: (S.Generator.Element) -> K) 
  -> [K:U] 
{

    var result: [K:U] = [:]

    for element in source {
        let key = groupBy(element)
        result[key] = combine(result[key] ?? initial, element)
    }

    return result
}

let a = [1,5,2,3,7]
let isEven = { $0 % 2 == 0 }
groupedReduce(a, 0, +, isEven)
// returns dictionary of two groupings, false (odd numbers)
// summing to 16 and true (even numbers) summing to 2
```

This should be easily adaptable to take a function that groups by the day of the week and does whatever summation logic you’re looking for.

Note, they key needs to be `Hashable`.  Your `getDayOfWeek` function returns an `Int?` and optionals aren’t hashable – but it doesn’t look like it needs to return an optional.  The day of the week can never be unknown given a date, so it should just return an `Int`, and they *are* hashable.

Comment: Interesting, just for curiosity, what is `U`? And how would you sum up all the values in `result` ?

Comment: Like with the regular `reduce`, the `combine` function doesn't have to return the same value as it's input.

Comment: For example, suppose you wanted to sum an array of strings of integers:
`let nums = ["1","2","3"]; let sum = reduce(nums, 0) { total, next in total + (next.toInt() ?? 0) }`.  Here the combine function takes a string and combines/returns an integer – so is of type `(A,B)->A` where `A` is `Int` and `B` is `String`.

Comment: Thanks, but how would you reduce the `value` only, from the dictionary? And did you answer about U in the previous comment? If so, I haven't understood your answer.

Comment: `U` is a placeholder for whatever type the combiner returns.  As to reducing the dictionary – you mean given a dictionary, how do you reduce all the values regardless of keys?  If your dictionary, contained values of type number, then for example you could sum them with `reduce(dict.values, 0, +)`.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity How can I adapt to my case as it generates the error "Cannot convert value of type '(Journal) -> Int' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'"?
       let byYear = { (journal: Journal) in
            journal.publication!.releaseDate!.year()
        }
        let groupedJournals = groupedReduce(journals, 0, +, byYear)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have dates and values in two separate arrays, maybe the simplest way can be:

```
let days = [NSDate]() // here your dates
let values = [Int]()  // here your values

typealias DayOfWeek = Int
typealias Value = Int

var result: [DayOfWeek : Value] = [:]
for (dayOfWeek, v) in Zip2(days.map(getDayOfWeek), values) {
    let a = result[dayOfWeek] ?? 0
    result[dayOfWeek] = a + v
}

result[1] // should give the sum for the first day of the week
```

Note I've changed your `getDayOfWeek() -> Int` as suggested by @Airspeed Velocity

Comment: I think you also have to add `v` to the previous result, otherwise it overwrites it?

Comment: Can you please explain line by line what your code does? It loops though 21 times in my code, which is correct. But, how do I access the sumMonday, sumTuesday etc.  Thank you - I apologise for my lower level of understanding.

Comment: `days.map(getDayOfWeek)` will a new array in which every index is the result of your function `getDayOfWeek` (i.e. it _maps_ an array into another using the given function). `Zip2` will _zip_ two arrays in a single array of tuples, thus you end up with an array of [(_the day of week_, _value_)]. Result is a dictionary with [_day of week_, _the corresponding sum_]. In the for loop `a` is set to `0` the first time a day of week is entered in the result dictionary. Then `a` is used as an _accumulator_.

Comment: I did a small edit using `type alias` it could help make the code clearer

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 2-Dimension array to make things a little less verbose such as:

```
var dateValues = Array<Array<Int>>()
for var i = 0; i < 7; i++ {
    dateValues.append(Array<Int>())
}
```

Then modifying your `appendValuesPerDayOfWeek` function to also an index instead of a range and inserting into the the 2-Dimension array looks like this:

```
func appendValuesPerDayOfWeek(){
    for var i = 0; i < nsDates.count; i++ {
        var dayOfWeek = getDayOfWeek(nsDates[i])
        dateValues[dayOfWeek].append(values[i])
    }
}
```

And then to get the sum of a day i'd write a function that looks like this:

```
func getSumForDayOfWeek(dayOfWeek: Int) -> Int {
    let array = dateValues[dayOfWeek]
    let sum = array.reduce(0,+)
    return sum
}
```

This reduces the amount of code. For bonus developer points, you could encapsulate these methods into your own data structure to simplify:

```
import UIKit

class DateValues: NSObject {
    var values = Array<Array<Int>>()

    override init() {
        for var i = 0; i < 7; i++ {
            values.append(Array<Int>())
        }
        super.init()
    }

    func addValue(value: Int, forDate date: NSDate) {
        var dayOfWeek = getDayOfWeek(date)
        values[dayOfWeek].append(value)
    }

    func sumFromDayOfWeek(dayOfWeek: Int) -> Int {
        let array = values[dayOfWeek]
        return array.reduce(0,+)
    }

    func getDayOfWeek(somedate: NSDate) -> Int {
        let calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let dateComps:NSDateComponents = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitWeekday , fromDate: somedate)
        let dayOfWeek:Int = dateComps.weekday
        return dayOfWeek
    }
}
```

If you really wanted to, you could probably make this generic as well to handle other types besides an Int, such as a Double or String.

I hope this helps